# Нереентерабельные функции в обработчиках сигналов

Tags: c, unix

Всем добрый вечер!
Есть задача освобождения ресурсов, используемых дочерними потоками, после их завершения. Меня очень просили реализовать данную операцию асинхронно, но, насколько я понимаю, функция free(), как и malloc(), не является реентерабельной и не рекомендуется к использованию в обработчиках сигналов. Я пока что вижу 2 пути :

1. выставлять флаг в обработчике сигналов, проверять его в основном потоке и освобождать память там,
2. блокировать сигнал перед каждым обращением к free() во всех потоках.

Если кто знает более интересные варианты решения, поделитесь пожалуста.

---

Некоторые уточнения : в основном потоке выполнения для каждого дочернего потока создается структура данных, она помещается в список, ее указатель передается дочернему потоку. По завершении дочернего потока необходимо удалить структуру из списка и освободить из-под нее память. Можно было бы делать это прямо в дочернем потоке, но, насколько я понимаю, хорошим тоном считается освобождение памяти, выделенной для дочернего потока, в основном потоке, где она и выделялась. Так как основной поток нагружен другой полезной работой, была озвучена просьба не ждать в нем завершения дочерних потоков, а обрабатывать их завершение асинхронно, в обработчике сигнала, вследствие чего я посылаю SIGUSR1 по завершении дочернего потока.

Comment: malloc() и free() **безусловно** в обработчике сигнала **нельзя**.

Времени, нет. Вечером м.б. подробно напишу.

Comment: Какая-то тут смесь получилась: потоки и обработчики сигналов. Уточните, пожалуйста, что Вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Внимательно прочитал вопрос и понял, что мне тоже необходимо уточнение. Не понимаю связи между завершением **потока (thread ?)** и сигналом, в обработчике которого надо освобождать ресурсы.

--

Вообще, какая-либо серьезная работа в signal handler не приветствуется. 

--

По поводу "безусловно" в своем предыдущем комментарии - я несколько погорячился. В *принципе* можно написать программу (используя блокировку сигналов) так, что malloc/free в обработчике и синхронной (в т.ч. в потоках) части не будут пересекаться. Но тут легко наделать ошибок и не учесть косвенные вызовы malloc/free

>>>

Comment: >>> продолжение

По поводу функций, которые *считается* можно вызывать из обработчика сигнала см. [здесь есть их список](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal)

Про malloc/free

Обычно при вызове из обработчика (один раз на миллион) процесс зависает на "самоблокировании" вызывая pthread_mutex_lock(). (Лично наблюдал из gdb).

Comment: Ситуация следующая : в основном потоке выполнения для каждого дочернего потока создается некоторая структура данных, она помещается в список, ее указатель передается дочернему потоку. По завершении дочернего потока необходимо удалить структуру из списка и освободить из-под нее память. Можно было бы делать это прямо в дочернем потоке, но, насколько я понимаю, хорошим тоном считается освобождение памяти, выделенной для дочернего потока, в основном потоке, где она и выделялась.

Comment: Основной поток в данном случае производит дополнительную работу, и меня просили не включать в его основной цикл отслеживание состояния завершения дочерних потоков, а сделать это асинхронно, в обработчике сигналов, поэтому по завершении дочернего потока я посылаю сигнал SIGUSR1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@margosh](/users/6966/margosh)](/users/6966/margosh), лимит комментариев у меня подошел к концу, поэтому переключаюсь на "ответ".

Не нравится мне идея делать free() в обработчике. Более того, я не понимаю, как Вы узнаете по получению SIGUSR1 что именно освобождать.

В подобной задаче (при Ваших условиях) я сделал бы что-то в таком духе:

1. Создал pipe,  который разделяют все потоки.
2. Создал поток, читающий этот pipe и освобождающий память.
3. Перед завершением потока (вместо SIGUSR1) писал в pipe, что освобождать.

Собственно как-то так. Без сигналов и асинхронно к основному циклу обработки. 
Если отбросить "правила хорошего тона", то проще всего (хотя я не знаю ряда тонкостей Вашей задачи) освобождать ресурсы в завершающемся потоке.

Comment: @avp, дочерний поток перед завершением выставляет в своей момнопольной структуре данных флаг о завершении, после получения сигнала я проверяю наличие установленных флагов по списку, хотя возможно это не самое удачное решение. Однако без сигналов не получится - так как есть еще и порожденные процессы, которые тоже используют области памяти, которые необходимо освободить по завершении, а процессы посылают SIGCHLD. Хотелось бы использовать идентичное решение для освобождения ресурсов как процессов, так и потоков.

Comment: Вы уверены, что на самом деле надо **асинхронно** обрабатывать завершение процессов ? 

А зачем освобождать память **после** завершения процесса ? Это можно сделать сразу после fork().

В принципе, обработчик SIGCHILD может безопасно делать write() в pipe (например для logger или статистики, посылая данные, полученные  из waitpid()).

Comment: @avp,>>"А зачем освобождать память после завершения процесса ?"
Потому что эта память используется в основном потоке, но хранит данные о порожденном процессе, такие как pid, адрес клиента, инициировавшего порождение данного процесса и тп. Соответственно, когда процесс по какой-то причине завершился, эти данные выводятся в log и больше не нужны. 
Согласна, завести еще один поток для освобождения ресурсов, и слушать в нем pipe можно. Спасибо!

Comment: Успехов. 

Добавить мьютекс для списка с данными теперь не забудьте.

Comment: Не забуду :)